# What does "At a point, the direction of magnetic field will be along the tangent drawn on the magnetic field at that point" mean?

Tags: electromagnetism

Can someone please explain the lines, i am not much of a physics geek and rather a layman. It would be good if there would be a diagram to help explain ,anyways your own discretion.

Answer (score 1):

At a point on a magnetic field line draw a tangent to that magnetic field line.
At that point the magnetic field is along the tangent which means that if you place a compass at that point the compass will align itself along the tangent as shown below.

[image]